# max string length in compose before clipping

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create a string with the max number of characters allowable in the box.

```
setContent {
    ViewincomposetestTheme {
        var size by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }
        var widthdp by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
        BoxWithConstraints(Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Yellow)) {
            val widthOfChar = 13 // how do I find this
            var string by remember {
                mutableStateOf(
                    StringBuffer()
                        .apply {
                            repeat(maxWidth.value.toInt() / widthOfChar) { append("H") }
                        }
                        .toString()
                )
            }
            Text(string)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll use a monospaced font so the specific char doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate `Text` to calculate the size of a character, which will report you its size with `onTextLayout`. Using `drawWithContent` you can prevent it from being drawn.

Also in your example you get the width using `maxWidth.value.toInt()`: here you get the value of `dp`, not pixels. You could convert it using `LocalDensity`, but you also get the pixel value directly from `BoxWithConstraints` using `constraints.maxWidth`.

```
BoxWithConstraints(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color.Yellow)
) {
    var charWidth by remember { mutableStateOf<Int?>(null) }
    val string = remember(maxWidth, charWidth) {
        charWidth?.let { charWidth ->
            StringBuffer()
                .apply {
                    repeat(constraints.maxWidth / charWidth) { append("H") }
                }
                .toString()
        }
    }
    Text(
        "H",
        onTextLayout = {
            charWidth = it.size.width
        },
        modifier = Modifier.drawWithContent { }
    )
    string?.let {
        Text(string)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `maxWidth` parameter of the `BoxWithConstraints`, then convert the obtained `dp` value `toPx()`. Decide a textsize for the `TextField` in `sp` and then do whatever calculations you want to do after converting that to Px as well. Max characters will be `maxWidth` / `textSize`, roughly.